# Using "find … -delete" to remove image files only from special subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu-14.04, linux-mint

I need to clean up some subdirectories inside my music collection from unwanted images. I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 and/or Linux Mint 17.2 and a bash shell script using the *find* command.

The directory structure (minimal example) is as follows:

```
Tagged
  Artist #1
    Artist #1 - An Album
      Artist #1 - A Track.flac
      cover.jpg
      something.png
    Artist #1 - [compilations]
      Artist #1 - A Track.flac
      cover.jpg
      something.png
  Artist #2
    Artist #2 - Another Album
      Artist #2 - A Track.mp3
      cover.jpg
```

*Only* in the subfolders ending with "[compilations]", I want to delete all kind of jpeg and/or png images (because the tagging software erroneously puts them there). Any images that happen to be in normal "album" folders I wish too keep.

With my directory structure, folders with "[compilations]" in the name can only happen just below the "Artist" folders, repectively; so a maximum of two levels deep.

I came up with the following find command:

```
$ cd Tagged
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*\[compilations\]' -exec find {} -type f -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' -delete \;
```

This seems to do something and takes a while, but the files *"./Artist #1/Artist #1 - [compilations]/cover.jpg"* and *"./Artist #1/Artist #1 - [compilations]/something.png"* are still there (and all other image files).

Being quite new to Linux, I assume I make a dumb mistake using *find*'s *-delete* option, because the following command (without *-delete*) shows the files correctly:

```
$ find . -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*\[compilations\]' -exec find {} -type f -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' \;
./Artist #1/Artist #1 - [compilations]/cover.jpg
./Artist #1/Artist #1 - [compilations]/something.png
```

So here are my questions:

- Why does the *-delete* not work?
- Is this command really safe regarding "extravaganza" like whitespace, glob characters and foreign characters in the paths and filenames?
- How would I have to rewrite the above command, still using *bash* and *find*?
- Could the command be optimized (re speed, safety, nested finds)?

In the actual collection, the command must traverse 16899 folders, almost all of them contain whitespace and foreign characters (like Czech, Russian, Japanese, Greek, German …), so it must be robust.

Thanks in advance for any insights and some enlightenment!

Comment: It's weird to have a `find` command inside a `find` command... Anyway, your delete only applies to the `-iname '*.png'` predicate, because you missed some groupings. To check what's going to happen, replace the `-delete` predicate by the `-print` predicate. You'll see that `find` misses all the jpg's. Use grouping: `\( -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' \)`

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf I can't really think of a way to do this with a single `find` command. I think `find`-from-`find` is the right way to go. You are spot on about the grouping, though; you should post that as an answer.

Comment: Thanks gniourf_gniourf! I just came up with the same idea, after some more experimentation. And yes, please post that as an answer, I’m glady willing to accept yours over mine ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `-delete` predicate only applies to the

```
-iname '*.png'
```

predicate, because you missed groupings: when you give `find` the following:

```
-type f -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' -delete
```

because of the precedence of the boolean operators, `find` understands:

```
\( -type f -iname '*.jp*g' \) -or \( -iname '*.png' -delete \)
```

To fix this, use:

```
-type f \( -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' \) -delete
```

I'd suggest that to experiment you replace `-delete` with `-print`: you'll see what the `-delete` applies to!

Now, regarding your nested `find`: because of the structure of your directory tree (your files are only in depth 3), you should be able to do with only one instance of `find`:

```
find -maxdepth 3 -path '*/*\[compilations\]/*' \( -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' \) -type f -print
```

(I put `-print` instead of `-delete` so that you can check the command before executing it with `-delete`).

Comment: Thanks for explaining @gniourf_gniourf! Sounds like a nice idea using only one find–then again, real life is more complicated. Would the path you gave still work when being invoked from somewhere else using something like: `find /home/$USER/Musik/Tagged/ -maxdepth 3 -path '*/*\[compilations\]/*' \( -iname '*.jp*g' -o -iname '*.png' \) -type f -print`?
Sorry for a dumb question, I’ve never used _-path_ before … still got to learn so much! :-)

Comment: @Moonbase Yes it will work! (try it, the `-print` instead of the `-delete` makes the command harmless). But quote your variable expansion: `"/home/$USER/Musik/Tagged"` (with double quotes).

Comment: Cheers again, just tried it, and it works beautifully. I guess not nesting _find_ will also be much faster, will time it later on on the real collection. Thanks for the hint on quating the $USER part … I _have_ no "odd" usernames, but you're right—always play safe! :-)

Comment: For those interested: On a music collection of 16899 folders in total, the "nested find" took 3.285s while gniourf_gniourf’s solution (only one find) took only 0.324s! (Used time’s real time for measuring.) Wow. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I think my error was in not putting the OR'ed part *in parentheses*—it seems *find* used the *-delete* only on the *right part of the last OR*, i.e., tried to delete '*.png'. Alas, almost all of my cover images were '*.jpg' so I thought it wouldn't work at all!

So I think the corrected command should be:

```
$ find . -depth -maxdepth 2 -type d -name '*\[compilations\]' -exec find {} -type f \( -iname '*.jp*g' -or -iname '*.png' \) -delete \;
```

It seems to work correctly on my test case above.

Nevertheless, some confirmation would be nice. An maybe some answers to my other questions, just for information and learning. *Thank you!*